# Oracle to delimited file in HDFS?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, datapump

I am working on a solution to transfer data from Oracle to HDFS. I looked into datapump, but there seems to no integration with HDFS. Another way would be looking into sqoop. But there are latency concerns with both the approaches.
Are there any other tools which can read from Oracle and push to HDFS ?

Comment: Have you had a look at Apache NiFi (https://nifi.apache.org/) ?

Comment: Oracle GoldenGate?